# C# how to write the whole array if a string within "array[1]" contains keyword

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach, element

My current code is looping through a list containing saved strings in an array. Currently it looks for all strings in that array. I want to change this so that it only goes through (searching, looking) for strings within "log[1]"

Sorry, i dont know the word for "log[1]". Im new to programming. Keep reading and i think you will understand.

This is how i want to do it:

```
foreach (string[] item[1] in loggbok)
```

item[1] being log[1]. Number 1 is very important because I want to search only within log[1].

This is my current code for saving the whole array in my list:

```
List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]> { };
string[] log = new string[3]; //date, title, post

DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

log[0] = "\n\tDate: " + date.ToLongDateString() + " Kl: " + date.ToShortTimeString();
Console.WriteLine(log[0]);

Console.Write("\tTitle: ");
log[1] = "\tTitle: " + Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\tPost: ");
log[2] = "\tPost: " + Console.ReadLine();

loggbok.Add(log);
log = new string[3];
```

I save "log[1],log[2],log[3]"

The following code i want to make a search function which goes through my list and recognise all the strings within log[1] aka titles. If a string title is containing the users keyword all logs should join and the log will be printed.

As of now. I solved this by searching through all logs(1,2,3). This means that my program is searching currently for strings within (titles, date, posts). This makes it so that you can search for messages or "post" when i want the user to be restricted by only searching for titles.

So i thought maby if in my foreach loop i make "item" to "item[1]". Will that make my code to only look for "log[1]". I did not get that far though becouse writing "item[1]" is invalid syntax.

Current search function:

```
string key;
Console.Write("\n\tSearch: ");
key = Console.ReadLine();

//Searching through all log[] in loggbok.
//I want to change this line to item[1]
foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
{
    //goes deeper and looks for all strings within log[].
    foreach (string s in item)
    {
        //if a string is found containing key word, this block will run.
        if (s.Contains(key))
        {
            foundItem = true;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item));

            index++;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, how about this?

Comment: I did not want to write a wall of text but since im an amature programmer i dont know the right words to make this question simpler to ask. Maby this is to extensive and if so i apologize. However, i hope this makes it easier to understand my problem.

Comment: i also tried to change the title to be more apropriate. I dont know what i call "log[1]" in C#. Is it an element, array, arraymember? i dont know. I can edit this when i know what it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do it like this:

```
var result = loggbok.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Any(s=> s.Contains(key));

Console.WriteLine(result?? "No record found");
```

Comment: can i do this in a similar fashion to my code?

i am new to programming and i get confused when i go outside of my knowledge base.

Comment: @Gobban okay try this and in your switch instead of the loops and see the result. You need System.Linq

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to loop, so what you need to do is retrieve the item from loggbok by the index.

```
// assign loggbokx of index 1, to variable item.
string[] item = loggbok[1];
// item will then have the 2nd (index=1) logbook.
// Note that index starts from 0.
// If you want to have the first one, then it should be loggbox[0]
// to make it even simpler you can write 
//     var item = loggbok[1];

// and the rest is the same...

//goes deeper and looks for all strings within log[].
foreach (string s in item)
{
    //if a string is found containing key word, this block will run.
    if (s.Contains(key))
    {
        foundItem = true;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item));

        index++;
    }  
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it only gives me the string at index [x] otherwise it sounded good. Simple and code i recognize. 

What i needed was to loop the array so that the if statement can access the strings within log[1]

Comment: in "step into" what i am trying to access is called "new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<string[]>(loggbok).Items[0][1]"

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it right!

Create a model class for your log:

```
class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Date: " + Date.ToLongDateString() + " Kl: " + Date.ToShortTimeString()
            + "\tTitle: " + Title + "\tPost: " + Post;
    }
}
```

Now we can comfortably use this model.

Let's populate the list with more records:

```
List<LogEntry> loggbok = new List<LogEntry>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
    entry.Date = DateTime.Now;
    entry.Title = "title" + i;
    entry.Post = "post" + i;

    loggbok.Add(entry);
}
```

Let's print it:

```
foreach (var entry in loggbok)
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

Due to the `ToString` method overload output looks out nice.

Let's find something:

```
string key = "title3";
var found = loggbok.Find(log => log.Title == key);
Console.WriteLine("Found:\n" + found);
```

We can use different [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `List` class, and [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx) extension methods.

---

If you need to save your data to a file and then read them from there, you can use json serialization.

For example, let's use the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) (don't forget to add a reference to the assembly):

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// Save
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", jss.Serialize(loggbok));

// Load
loggbok = jss.Deserialize<List<LogEntry>>(File.ReadAllText("test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution if anyone finds it intressting.

```
foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
{
   foreach (string s in item)
   {
      //This was the magic line.
      string searchTitle = item[1].ToLower();

      if (searchTitle.Contains(titleKey.ToLower()))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\tSearch hit #" + index);

         foundItem = true;

         Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item));

         index++;

         break;
      }
   }
}
```